# Java, MySQL: myStatement.executeUpdate INSERT INTO gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, database, nullpointerexception, sql-insert

**The Problem:**

`java.lang.NullPointerException
at mainPackagePaketverwaltung.Datenbank.savePaket(Datenbank.java:58)
at mainPackagePaketverwaltung.MainPV$12.actionPerformed(MainPV.java:507)`

**The Cause:**

This is the Line (58):

```
myStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Relation VALUES(NULL, '"+ PaketID +"', '"+ atodb.getArtikelID() + "', '"+ atodb.getMenge() +"')");
```

From what i understand this should create a new line in the Database because the NULL/Primary_Key is set to Auto_Increment, but after one runt it errors out.

That should not happen bc with each run a new line would be made by the Auto_Increment.

**More Info:**

PaketID is a INT

atodb.getArtikelID is a INT

atodb.getMenge is a INT

All DB Fields are INT,s

Comment: are you sure that `atodb` is not null?

Comment: and also `myStatement` should not be null

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, i can confirm (just checked with a System.out.print) they are not null, the first set of data makes it to the DB but the seconds errors out even with data in it

Comment: @guleryuz i set it to null after the .executeUpdate is that wrong?

Comment: Yes...that seems wrong

Comment: can you post `savePaket` method body

Comment: @gargkshitiz yep, that fixed it, i did never even think about it because in my mind that should not have be a problem if its after the execute bet there we are.

Thx for the Quick help! :)

Comment: can you show us the full code please, @gargkshitiz is correct, what if your transaction is not yet committed and you already set the object to null? and please read about ¨Prepared Statement your code is a victim of SQL Infection and error syntax

Comment: @gargkshitiz

`public static boolean savePaket(int PaketID, Artikel atodb) {
  try {
   myCon=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
   System.out.println(atodb.getArtikelID());
   System.out.println(atodb.getMenge());
   myStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Relation VALUES(NULL, '"+ PaketID +"', '"+ atodb.getArtikelID() + "', '"+ atodb.getMenge() +"')");
   //myStatement=null; <= Dont do that anymore!
   myRS=null;
   return true;
  } catch (Exception e) {

   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  
  return false; 
 }`

Comment: @LifeLifeLP Please put the code as an edit into your question and not in the comments. without proper indention it's a nightmare to read.

Comment: @L.Spillner Sorry, i was to late before this was closed, i will do it however next time i asksometing here :S

Comment: myCon , myStatement seem to be class level variables, hence assigning null to them means the 2nd method call will throw NPEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure following

- myStatement is not null
- atodb is not null